# Define variables using a list of names

Tags: python, variables, loops

I am trying to do something dirty here in my script.

I have a function that applies some transformations on an object called `model`. `model` can have several attributes, which includes `alpha` and `delta`. The function, however, must be able to override those attributes with its own optional parameters.

I guess I have to check if the function has received those arguments and, if not, reassign the attribute to the flat name. (From `model.alpha` to `alpha`). The main issue here is to code the loop that solves this for any given case.

The only way I have managed to do this is using the `locals()` dict, but I find that quite dirty. Any suggestions? Here is my code, roughly.

```
 def transform(model, alpha=None, theta=None):
        for p in ('alpha', 'theta'): #the list is longer, actually
            if not locals()[p] and hasattr(model, p):
                locals()[p] = getattr(model, p)

        _rotate(model, alpha)
        _translate(model, delta)
```

Finally, is there any internal list for the optional parameters of the function? Something like `__parameters__`? That way, I could just do `for p in __parameters__` and so on.

Thank you!

Comment: `def transform(model, **kwargs):` gives you a dictionary of keyword arguments in `kwargs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `**kwargs` syntax, and then operate directly on that `kwargs` dictionary rather than the locals:

```
def transform(model, **kwargs):
    for p in ('alpha', 'theta', ...):
        if 'p' not in kwargs and hasattr(model, p):
            kwargs[p] = getattr(model, p)
```

(You probably still want to explicitly iterate through a list of expected names, to filter out any unexpected arguments that might also be in kwargs.)

Comment: Hi, thank you. I thought of using **kwargs, but that meant losing default values in the `def`statement. I would have to iterate the **kwargs dict to test if the parameter is in there. 

That's why I ended up using locals(), but I don't know if that's a bad idea for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your function like this:

```
def transform(model, **kwargs):
    ...
```

then all keyword arguments will be passed to the function in `kwargs` as a dictionary.